# Couldn't import Go standard libraries

Tags: go, environment-variables

I am configuring GOPATH and GOBIN in .bash_profile & .zshrc to make godoc works, but I might have done something wrong.

Here is what I added in .zshrc

```
export GOROOT=~/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$GOBIN:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

then I moved my workspace directory inside ~/go/src to make godoc works

Now when I run `go mod tidy`
it throws me

```
imports encoding/json: no Go source files
```

the files it couldn't find sources are from standard library like ioutil, fmt, http

And when I `go run` or `go test` something
it throws me

```
import "": import of unknown directory
```

I tried remove all files in /usr/local/go and reinstall Go, but the problem still persists. I don't know what to do from here could you guys enlighten me?

here is my go env

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/bin"
GOCACHE="/Users/User/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/User/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH=""
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/Users/User/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/Users/User/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.19.4"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/User/go/src/go-klix/go-testing/go.mod"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/xy/dj6ry6jx4d78qcvm0nd3pzfr0000gp/T/go-build871628837=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Comment: You set GOROOT. That’s just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out now.

The problem is `GOTOOLDIR="/Users/User/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"`, which is my  User's go folder and it doesn't have darwin_amd64 compiler.

So I change GOROOT to `/usr/local/go`, which is where the Go compiler actually are then `source .zshrc` and reopen my terminal.

Now it works well as before.

Comment: Setting GOROOT to anything is incorrect here. There is no documentation which ever says to set that variable.